# How to support iPhone X in swift 1.2 project?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an swift 1.2 project, which can runs in Xcode 7.2.1. And now need to support iPhoneX. Xcode 9 cannot compile the project.

Is there anyway Xcode 7.2.1 can run iPhoneX simulator? or must need to upgrade the project which I don't want to.

Thanks.

Comment: You **have to** update it to Swift 3.2/4. There's no any other option.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to update your project to **at least** Swift 3.2, which is the last Swift Version supported by Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the project? Xcode has Swift upgrade wizard built. If you just want to run a Simulator, you can make a copy of your project, upgrade it to current Swift supported in Xcode 9 and run it as test.